# Efficient Matrix multiplication in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, matrix-multiplication, riscv

I am struggling with matrix multiplication in RISC-V

Input is 128*128 matrix with unsigned short integer entry

I've wrote a naive one

The goal is to reduce the clock cycles

• Below 20,000,000 cycles (2%)
• Below 18,000,000 cycles (2%)
• Below 16,000,000 cycles (2%)
• Below 14,000,000 cycles (2%)
• Below 12,000,000 cycles (2%)
• Below 10,000,000 cycles (1%)
• Below 9,000,000 cycles (1%)
• Below 8,000,000 cycles (1%)
• Below 7,000,000 cycles (1%)
• Below 6,000,000 cycles (1%)

Mine is about 19M

and bruteforce in C with O3 is 16M

I know there's the a better algorithm to do matrix multiplication o(n^3)

but here n is only 128, I wonder if there's other way to reduce cycles by the O(n^3) algo

is there anything can I do to boost my code?

```
.global matrix_mul
.type matrix_mul, %function

.align 2
# void matrix_mul(unsigned int A[][], unsigned int B[][], unsinged int C[][]);
matrix_mul:
    
    # for i = 0 to 127
    #   for j = 0 to 127
    #       for k = 0 to 127
    #           C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j] % 1024

    # insert code here
        addi t0, zero, 128 # size
        add s11, zero, a1 # B

        add t1, zero, zero # i = 0 
loop1:  # loop1 #
        add t2, zero, zero # j = 0
        # loop2 #
loop2:   
        add t3, zero, zero # k = 0
        add t4, zero, zero # sum = 0
        # loop3 #
loop3:
        lhu t5, 0(a0) # A[i][k]
        lhu t6, 0(s11) # B[k][j]
        mul t5, t5, t6 # A*B
        add t4, t4, t5 # C += A*B
        andi t4, t4, 1023 # mod 1024
        addi a0, a0, 2 # A[i][k+1]
        addi s11, s11, 256 # B[k+1][j]
        addi t3, t3, 1 # k++ 
        blt t3, t0, loop3 # k<size , continue
        # loop3 end #
        sh t4, 0(a2) # store back to C[i][j]
        addi a2, a2, 2 # C[i][j+1]
        addi a0, a0, -256 # A go back
        addi a1, a1, 2 # B[k][j+1]
        add  s11, zero, a1 # B
        addi t2, t2, 1 # j++
        blt t2, t0, loop2 # j<size , continue
        # loop2 end #
        addi a0, a0, 256 # A[i+1][k]
        addi a1, a1, -256 # B go back (because line 40 add 2*128=256)
        add s11, zero, a1 # B
        addi t1, t1, 1 # i++
        blt t1, t0, loop1 # i<size , continue
        # loop1 end #

    # Green card here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/ECAD+Arch/files/docs/RISCVGreenCardv128-20151013.pdf

    ret
```

Comment: Does your RISC-V CPU have data caches?  If so, then cache-blocking can be important for matrices that don't fit in L1d.  It's O(n^3) work on O(n^2) data, so organizing for reuse and cache locality is important.